# Search all Server Shares for a wildcard filename

Tags: powershell, server, share, network-shares

I'm looking for a PowerShell script that will search all shares on a server for a wildcard of `*_HELP_instructions*`. An example of a files that it would search for would be `12_HELP_INSTRUCTIONS.txt` or `22_HELP_INSTRUCTIONS.html`.

So far I have the script below that will search the contents of the C:\, but I need a script that I can setup to search server shares instead.

```
$FilesToSearch = Get-ChildItem "C:\*" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                 where {$_.Name -like "*_HELP_instructions*"}

if ($FilesToSearch -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "System Infected!" 
    exit 2015
} else {
    Write-Host "System Not Infected!" 
    exit 0
}
```

Comment: Do you want to run the script against a particular share on a remote server? All shares? Locally on all shared folders of a server?

Comment: Hi Ansgar, the script will be running locally on a server so should scan all local shares of that specific server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-WmiObject` to enumerate the shared folders on the server:

```
$exclude = 'Remote Admin', 'Remote IPC', 'Default share'
$shared  = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share |
           Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_.Description } |
           Select-Object -Expand Path
```

The `Where-Object` clause excludes the administrative shares from being scanned (otherwise you could simply scan all local drives).

Then call `Get-ChildItem` with the resulting list of paths:

```
$FilesToSearch = Get-ChildItem $shared -Filter '*_HELP_instructions*' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Ansgar, thanks very much for this, it is exactly what i am after. added this to my script and its working a treat

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ForEach Loop` to loop through all the paths you are required to search through.

```
$paths = Get-Content C:\Temp\Pathlist.txt

Foreach($path in $paths){
   $Filestosearch = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -ErrorAction SiltenlyContinue| where {$_.Name -like "*_HELP_instructions*"}
   If($FilesToSearch -ne $null) {
      Write-Host "System Infected!" 
   $Filestosearch | Export-Csv c:\Temp\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
   } else {
      Write-Host "System Not Infected!" 
      }
}
```

This will loop through each `$path` in the `C:\Temp\PathList.txt` file. (e.g. `C:\*` or `\\ServerName\MyShare\*`)

Then push the output to `C:\Temp\Result.csv`. If the System is Infected.

This will take a while to run depending on how many paths you put in the txt file. But it will achieve what you are after!

Hope this helps!

Comment: HI Lachie, thanks for your comments. I have never really touched Powershell before but the above script is pretty much how i need the process to run, in the sense that i need it to scan for a filename and then report if the system is clean or infected and then exit with a specific code as detailed in my code snippet. Ideally i need to keep the script snippet as close to how it currently is i just need it to scan a local server shares instead of just a C:\ and output the result in the same manner as my current script if its possible?

Comment: Hi @MarkSmith, Always good to have another person using powershell! i have **edited the above code** to reflect the snippet you had use previously. It will now output to the screen if it is infected or not. If it is infected store that information in the CSV

Comment: Hi Lachie, this is looking more promising :) one last request, is there any way that the script can identify the server's local shares by its self instead of relying on a txt file with the shares manually typed out? This wouldn't be an issue if we only had a couple of servers but we are supporting many servers across our client base.

Comment: Hi Mark, Umm there is a few ways to do that. I would recommend:
**Option 1:**http://superuser.com/questions/769679/powershell-get-list-of-folders-shared
**Option 2:**https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwih5dSZo_HQAhWCkJQKHfEpCvEQFgg2MAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fjj635704.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFF-E9mqeve7R7Z93_HxGhhTL7a-g

It would also depend on the Technology you are using for your shares. i.e. CIFS or SMB etc..

Comment: Hi Mark, Glad you found your solution if you are able to mark an answer so the question can be marked as completed that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much guys for your feedback. Taking all of your coments into account the final code was as follows:

```
$exclude = 'Remote Admin', 'Remote IPC', 'Default share'
$shared  = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share |
       Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_.Description } |
       Select-Object -Expand Path

$FilesToSearch = Get-ChildItem $shared -Filter '*_HELP_instructions*' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If($FilesToSearch -ne $null) 

{
Write-Host "System Infected!" 
exit 2015
}

else 

{
Write-Host "System Clear!" 
exit 0
}
```